# How to use ajax call to retrieve data from craft cms entries to use in php application

Tags: craft3, php, ajax, vue, js

I'm building a static webpage with php and Javascript. I have setup all my data in craft cms entries. I want to use ajax to retrieve the data from craft and just display it on my webpage. How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to expose some sort of API that your JavaScript can use to request data from your Craft install.

There are two first-party options:

1. Craft CMS has had [GraphQL](https://graphql.org/) support built into core since version 3.3.0. [The official docs](https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/graphql.html) provides a fairly comprehensive guide to get up and running.
2. If you prefer a RESTful JSON API, the first-party [Element API plugin](https://plugins.craftcms.com/element-api?craft3) provides a simple interface to configure your endpoints. The documentation for Element API can be found [on the plugin's GitHub page](https://github.com/craftcms/element-api). The Element API plugin is available for both Craft 3 and 4.

Aside from the above, if you happen to use Gatsby for your site there's also a first-party [Gatsby source plugin](https://github.com/craftcms/gatsby-source-craft) for Craft.

Finally, when using Craft as a CMS for a headless app/site, it's also worth knowing about the [`headlessMode`](https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/config/general.html#headlessmode), which "optimizes the system and control panel for headless CMS implementations".